# Keep application thread alive when using CameraCaptureTask

Tags: c#, multithreading, camera, windows-phone-7

I have an application where I'm using the CameraCaptureTask however I have a thread running in my application that needs to be used after a picture has been taken - however when my application is suspended this includes any threads - I can store state or settings but I need to keep this Thread running to return some data to a service - what can I use other than rolling my own Camera Task in my app which won't be as good as the Camera task which works but suspends my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CameraCaptureTask can cause your app to be tombstoned and this is what's stopping your thread.

The solution should be to manage the state of any background threads such that they are restarted after tombstoning. I assume that you'll also want to restart your thread after tombstoning in ways other via the chooser so rolling your own version of the task wouldn't completely solve the issue anyway.

Comment: Thanks I had the feeling this would be the answer - my solution was to roll my own Camera Capture system using the direct camera API as the thread connects to an online service, when ended it disconnects, this is a third-party solution I have to use and can't make it not do that!